# Should I have multiple views for a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building a new application to process submissions. The user will be required to enter different information based on the submission type. Sections of data shared by multiple submission types are placed in partial views.

Should I have one controller that handles all submission types, approximately 6, and displays the requested view. Or should I have a different controller for each submission type?

Comment: Most of the time, you handle similar transaction or model related transaction in one controller. For example, all Employee transaction are handled under one EmployeeController, and all views are connected to this controller including its partial views.

Comment: Try to keep data same fields in view and place different fields in partial view. Get data in one controller action method by using if condition . its up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to make different controllers for each submission.
just handle the POST methods in same controller.